What is an efficient way to simulate a fair die using a fair coin? Help with my approach
Given a fair coin, how can you efficiently simulate a fair six-sided die? According to the course I'm taking, my approach is incorrect. However, the reasoning is less than understandable.
My Approach
Initial Strategy
Toss the coin thrice and use the following mapping to convert from the result to the die roll.
$HHH=1, HHT=2, HTH = 3, HTT = 4, THH = 5, THT = 6, TTH = TTT = $ discard and redo three flips
With this strategy, the expected number of coin flips it will take to simulate one die roll is (expected number of trials until success)*(number of flips in one trial) = $\frac{1}{\frac{6}{8}}\times{3}=4$. But can we do better? Here are the next steps I took:
Efficient Strategy
Instead of discarding $TTH$ and $TTT$ let us keep flipping the coin and see if we get any of the desirable outcomes that we know have a mapping to a die roll. So we are essentially waiting for the first occurrence of a known outcome.
$E(X) = \frac{6}{8}(3) + \frac{1}{8}(3+E_{TTH}) + \frac{1}{8}(3+E_{TTT})$
where $E_{TTT}=$ expected number of flips to come to an end after we get $TTT$ and $E_{TTH}=$ expected number of flips to come to an end after we get $TTH$
We see that if the first three flips yield $TTH$ the next flip will decide the outcome of the roll for us (either 5 or 6). So $E_{TTH}=1$. On the other hand, we can set up an equation for $E_{TTT}$
$E_{TTT}=P(head)\cdot (1+E_{TTH}) + P(tail)\cdot (1 + E_{TTT}) \implies E_{TTT}=3$
Therefore, $E(X)=\frac{7}{2}$.
Is this right?

What is the probability that you end up with the result $1$ at the end of your procedure? What about $6$? (But yes, you can do better than an expected $4$ coin tosses.)

So I will get 1 with probability $P_{HHH}=\frac{1}{8}$. And, I will get 6 with a probability $\frac{1}{4}$. So, are you suggesting that this is why my approach is wrong? Because 1 and 6 don't have the same probability now?

I'm increasingly beginning to think that this is the reason my strategy is wrong. The course's approach is to take only the most recent flip (third flip) into consideration for the future flips, not the most recent two flips like I am doing. With their strategy, the probabilities for all numbers remain equal. But is there any intuition here? How could I have realized early that my strategy would yield unequal probabilities?

Of cause you have to evaluate the probability of your choices.

You understood me perfectly. It seems you know the answer now.

okay thank you!

To get closer to the information theoretic optimum $\log_2(6)\approx2.58,$ you can generate batches of dice based on batches of coinflips and look for values of $m$ and $n$ for which $2^m$ is relatively close to $6^n$ and use the naive rejection sampling approach (or maybe make a slight improvement to the naive approach if that's possible, as it is for your original case). For instance, $6^5=7776$ and $2^{13}=8192,$ so making $5$ dice rolls out of (possibly repeated) sequences of 13 coin flips using the naive approach gives an average of $(8192/7776)*13/5\approx 2.74$ coin flips per dice roll.

Flip the coin once to determine whether the "roll" will be odd or even. Then flip twice more to assess the residue $\bmod 3$. The resulting ordered pair of residues may be mapped bijectively into a unique number in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.
You still have to reflip on one of the four possible outcomes in the second stage, but because the reflip involves only two flips instead of three the expected total number of flips is $1+[2×(4/3)]=3+(2/3)<4$.

Alternatively, to reach the same expected number of coin flips, use the exact scheme as in the OP, but if the first two flips are TT, start over right away rather than flipping a third time and discarding the outcome.

Yup, thanks for your answers. This makes sense!
